# What is the antecedent of 'which'?

Tags: usage

In my opinion, the antecedent of ***which***(line8) is not ***ethnic identity or geographical location*** but ***culture-based differences***. But why is it used as defining clause, not non-defining one? The former doesn't make sense to me.

> From a sociological perspective, it has been useful to view the
> construct of culture from a somewhat dichotomous perspective in which
> the notion of the cultural insider can be contrasted with that of the
> cultural outsider. Contemporary scholarship has drawn attention to the
> complexity of this comparison and the considerable subjectivity that
> lies at the heart of such an often, oversimplified bifurcation.
> Although music is often associated with cultural identity and
> therefore susceptible to insider/outsider categorization, the ease
> with which an individual interacts with any given culture’s music may
> be more nuanced. Culture-based differences in the way listeners and
> performers interact with and respond to music are often delineated by
> ethnic identity or geographical location ***which*** are, in turn,
> generally treated as categorical constructs. As such, they tend to
> oversimplify complex relationships, obscure considerable within-group
> variability, and, most critically, do not hold up well when
> considering a brain-based understanding of music processing.

Comment: I'd say it refers to "ethnic identity or geographical location". It should probably be non-defining.

Comment: But if 'which' refers to 'ethnic identity or geographical location', shouldn't the verb be  'is', not 'are,' because 'a singular or a singular noun' is followed by a singular verb?

Comment: With my current display settings, the bold "which" appears not on line 8 but on line 23.

Answer (score 1):

According the the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-turn), the words "in turn" mean "because of that". The example is a sentence where A causes B, and B causes C. Here is the example:

> Stress causes your body to release chemicals, which in turn boost blood pressure

A is stress which causes B the release of chemicals, and B causes C boosted blood pressure.

In your example A is Culture based differences, B is ethnic identity or geographic location and C is categorical constructs. The sentence relates not to causality, but the sequence of analysis that people (wrongly, in the opinion of the author) use: A can be analysed as B, and B can be analysed as C.

I would probably interpret it as I have explained without **in turn**. With those words, that's definitely the meaning.